# managedObjectContext unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am following a tutorial to develop an iOS app. I am using core data. The first view of the app is `RootViewController`. All Core Data stack is on the `AppDelegate` file. This is the part of the code from `AppDelegate.m` that makes the call to the `RootViewController` file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  // Fetch the data to see if we ought to pre-populate
  NSError *error = nil;
  if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
  }

  [self loadFavoriteThingsData];        

  RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController *)[navigationController topViewController];
  [rootViewController setManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];       

  [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
  [window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

Now, in another part of the app I need to open a new view Controller that is a duplicate of `RootViewController`, called `DoneViewController`, but using other `NSPredicate`s to show other core data objects.

In `RootViewController` there is a button to open the `MenuViewController` file, from there I try to open `DoneViewController` using following method:

```
- (IBAction)doneToDoaction:(id)sender {
    DoneViewController *viewController = [[DoneViewController alloc] init];

    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

but an exception is fired:

```
[MenuViewController managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x145a0c00
2013-12-26 22:58:23.688  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MenuViewController managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I guess I have to pass the `managedObjectContext` from `RootViewController` to `MenuViewController` and then from `MenuViewController` to `DoneViewController`, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: you don't have to pass the managedObjectContext from one viewcontroller to another you can do it eaisly by making a instance of managedObjectContext in appDelegate and use that context where ever you need by simply making the instance of the appDelegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few solutions to do what you want.

The first is to expose the context from the application delegate as @Gyanendra commented. The second is to pass the context from controller to controller. For further references I really suggest to read [PASSING AROUND A NSMANAGEDOBJECTCONTEXT ON IOS](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/01/07/passing-around-a-nsmanagedobjectcontext-on-the-iphone/) by Marcus Zarra.

Anyway, I would prefer the second solution. Passing around the context or grabbing by an instance of `NSManagedObject`. Based on the latter each `NSManagedObjectInstance` has a reference to the context has been registered in.

```
[managedObjectInstance managedObjectContext];
```

These solutions prevent to have a rigid application and avoid to pollute the application delegate.

In your case, you could just follow this approach. From `RootViewController` pass the context to `MenuViewController` and then, from the latter, pass it to `DoneViewController`. How?

Simple enough. Just expose properties like for the controller you are interested in (`MenuViewController` and `DoneViewController` in this case).

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext* mainContext;
```

that can be set as

```
// from RootViewController
menuViewController.mainContext = [self managedObjectContext];
```

Comment: Thank you, I will implement your proposal and later I will tell you if I could manage to solve my issue. Thank you also for editing my question...

Comment: Hi again, it is working as you said, but now I have to deal with another issue which I will try to deal by myself, the navigation bar on DoneViewController isn't showed...thank you @flexaddicted for your great help and patience.

Comment: @mvasco Could you add some details or even open a new question for the problem?

Comment: Hi, I have just open a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810276/no-navigation-bar-in-view

Answer (score 8):

This is due to that you are not using NSObject class. For this you have to implement NSObject in you AppDelegate.h.Like this..

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,NSObject>{
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

and also add the properties.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;
```

Also add code in AppDelegate.m file...

```
 - (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return managedObjectContext;
    }
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
    }

    return managedObjectContext;
}

 - (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel;
    }
    managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil] ;

    return managedObjectModel;
}

 - (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator

 {

    if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }
    NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self  applicationDocumentsDirectory]
                                               stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"<Project Name>.sqlite"]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]
                                  initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
        if(![persistentStoreCoordinator      addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil   URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]) 
  {
        /*Error for store creation should be handled in here*/
  }

    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}
```

This works for me 100%. Hope so that it work for you.